# How to set a js var from a rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 controllers that render a single view and I need the view to change depending on my controller. What I have in mind is to have a JS var in my view that I can set depending on which controller was called.

To be a bit more thorough on my explanation, I need to get a string value set inside a var so I can use it like this (in a piece of JS on the application.js):

```
if (value_i_set_in_controller == "controller1") {
   // do something
} else {
   // do something else
}
```

Any hints? Until know I have been finding Rails pretty easy.

## EDIT

I need to explain a bit more.

I have some js in my application.js which renders some objet.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
...
    // a future calendar might have many sources.
    eventSources: [{
        url: '/DYNAMIC_PATH',
        color: 'yellow',
        textColor: 'black',
        ignoreTimezone: true
    }],
```

I render this simply by having a calendar view with this :

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

I was thinking of doing something like this in the calendar view:

```
<div id='calendar'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var calendar_source = <% @dyn_path %>;
</script>
```

Evidently it does not work... with this I would be able to read calendar_source var and us it in my js to set the eventSources properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just missing quotes :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var calendar_source = '<%= @dyn_path %>';
</script>
```

Anyway I need this kind of assignation often, it works perfectly :)
If it still doesn't work, look at the generated code and the JS console (firebug, chrome debugger ...)

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
if (<%= @your_value.to_json %> == "controller1")
```

Comment: In the view? Where is the @your_value coming from? I'm a 3 week old Rail programmer (many years elsewhere). I mean, what controller will be rendering this?

Comment: Yes this should live in the view, it's js code right? @value should be created in your controller

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is a clean way to do but here it goes:

In my application.js I put

```
    eventSources: [{
        url: '/events/' + $('#calendar_event_path').data("value"),
        color: 'yellow',
        textColor: 'black',
        ignoreTimezone: true
    }],
```

Then in each controller is set a value like this:

```
@calendar_event_path = "company_events_index"
```

Then my view looks like this:

```
<div id='calendar'></div>

<div id='calendar_event_path' data-value='<%= @calendar_event_path %>'></div>
```